# Strange process running

Tags: debian, malware

I just mentioned that one user starts a process which is called "httpd".

```
31712 ftp_johndoe  20   0 35988  8828  1460 S 14.0  0.0  1h50:31 httpd
28616 ftp_johndoe  20   0 5304M 43936 35080 S  4.0  0.2  0:02.72 /usr/bin/php5-cgi -c /var/www/vhosts/system/johndoe.net/etc/php.ini
31711 ftp_johndoe  20   0 35808  8608  1460 S  1.0  0.0  1h51:15 httpd
```

Well, I wondered why the process is called "httpd", because on debian apache starts no processes called "httpd".

If I lsof it I'm getting the following results:

```
httpd     28868            ftp_johndoe  txt       REG              253,0     10456   12335127 /usr/bin/perl
httpd     28868            ftp_johndoe  mem       REG              253,0     22952   12335108 /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/File/Glob/Glob.so
httpd     28868            ftp_johndoe  mem       REG              253,0    109888   12335102 /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
httpd     28868            ftp_johndoe  mem       REG              253,0     18672   12335109 /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
httpd     28868            ftp_johndoe  mem       REG              253,0     39256   12980353 /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Socket/Socket.so
httpd     31712            ftp_johndoe   63u     IPv4          520937935       0t0        TCP server.name.com:38504->64.233.165.26:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd     31712            ftp_johndoe   67u     IPv4          520937969       0t0        TCP server.name.com:38536->64.233.165.26:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd     31712            ftp_johndoe   73u     IPv4          520937951       0t0        TCP server.name.com:38520->64.233.165.26:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
```

So I guess this is malware. But how can I find the script that starts the httpd process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start finding the executable using

```
ls -l /proc/<PID>/exe
```

Then you can find who created it (the parent PID) with

```
ps -p <PID> -o ppid=
```

And search until you find the starting point.

You can also check the common automatic execution points, like init scripts, global and user specific cron jobs, `at` scripts, `rc.local` files

**UPDATE:** I just reminded of a program called [snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy) that

> Snoopy is a tiny library that logs all executed commands (+ arguments) on your system.

It could very useful to use it to check the command execution

This is not a complete solution, I'm aware there are simple ways to circumvent this. Hopefully someone with more experience than me we'll be more helpful

Comment: `pstree` will draw a diagram of a proces tree (automating some of what you describe). Try `pstree -upaA`. See man page for more details.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to learn myself how to do it manually! Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot - with your help I was able to delete the script :-)